# Java main thread does not wake for ServerSocket accept

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, http

I am creating a simple web proxy app using java. Basically, the main method creates a RequestReceiver object which has a ServerSocket listening for web browser http requests. A new Connection object is created from the socket returned from serverSocket.accept() and is put into a pool of threads.

The problem I am having is that not all of the http GET requests seem to be getting picked up by the serverSocket. For example on one webpage I was testing, I could see that only 7 out of 10 GET requests were received by the proxy server. This causes the web page to hang and take a long time to load. What could cause the thread with the serverSocket.accept() function to not always get priority to execute when a new connection is made?

RequestReceiver.java

```
public class RequestReceiver {
    public static final int LISTENING_PORT = 4000;
    public static final int CONNECTION_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 30;

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private ThreadPoolExecutor connectionThreads;

    public RequestReceiver() throws IOException{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(LISTENING_PORT);
        connectionThreads = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CONNECTION_THREAD_POOL_SIZE, CONNECTION_THREAD_POOL_SIZE, 
                1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    }

    public void start(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Current Pool Size: " + connectionThreads.getPoolSize() 
                    + " Active threads: " + connectionThreads.getActiveCount() );
            Connection conn = new Connection(serverSocket.accept());
            System.out.println("Created a new connection thread. Request from " + conn.clientSocketToString());
            connectionThreads.execute(conn);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception occured when accepting a new connection.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Connection.java

```
public class Connection implements Runnable{

public static final int REPLY_CHUNK_SIZE = 32768;
public static final int DEFAULT_WEB_SERVER_PORT = 80;
public static final int SERVER_SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 0; // milliseconds
public static final int CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 0; // milliseconds

private Socket clientSocket, serverSocket;
private InputStream clientIS, serverIS;
private OutputStream clientOS, serverOS;

public Connection(Socket clientSocket){
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    // set client socket timeout
    try{
        clientSocket.setSoTimeout(CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
    }catch(SocketException soe){
        soe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String connection = "";
    try{
        // setup client streams
        clientIS = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        clientOS = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        // get the request from the browser
        String request = "";
        String hostname = "";
        String[] hostAndPort = new String[2];
        request = browserInputStreamToString(clientIS);
        hostname = getHostName(request);
        hostAndPort = hostname.split(":");
        connection = "Connection to: " + hostname + " from " + clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName() 
                + ":" + clientSocket.getPort() + " Request: " + request.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"))[0];
        System.out.println("OPENED>> " + connection);
        // Attempt to create socket to server
        serverSocket = new Socket(hostAndPort[0], (hostAndPort.length > 1 ? new Integer(hostAndPort[1]):DEFAULT_WEB_SERVER_PORT));
        // set timeout
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(SERVER_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
        // Set up server streams
        serverIS = serverSocket.getInputStream();
        serverOS = serverSocket.getOutputStream();
        // send client request to server
        serverOS.write(request.getBytes());
        serverOS.flush();
        // send server response to client in chunks
        byte[] reply = new byte[REPLY_CHUNK_SIZE];
        int replyLength = serverIS.read(reply);
        while( replyLength != -1 ){
            clientOS.write(reply, 0, replyLength);
            clientOS.flush();
            replyLength = serverIS.read(reply);
        }
        // close sockets
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            if(clientSocket != null){
                clientSocket.close();
            }
            if(serverSocket != null){
                serverSocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("CLOSED>> " + connection);
}
```

EDIT: removed return statements from catch statements

Comment: your server socket looks like it accepts a single connection and then exits.  is something continuously calling the start method?

Comment: @jtahlborn The main class has a while(true) loop continuously calling the start() method

Comment: Don't write code like this. You should only have one `catch (IOException)` block per method. Code that depends on the success of code in a `try` block should be inside the same `try` block. And don't flush inside loops.

Comment: Does it print 10 "Created a new connection thread. Request from"?

Comment: @EJP My thinking when I was writing this code was that it would help me see when debugging the code at what stage things are going wrong by printing a different message. I have edited my question to include cleaned up code.

Comment: @user123345 It only prints 7/8 Created a new connection thread when there should be 10. (I can see that firefox made 10 GET requests for the particular website I was loading)

Comment: @Darkphenom The stack trace already does that.

Answer (score 0):

When you say 7 out of 10 , you mean you tested 10 times or several times and got this rate? I ask because the default queue size is 50, so if you tested a lot, you might have a queue problem. If you have not change the queue size..

Other thing, also about the queue size. You have several returns and try-caches. If anything happens you will not get to the point your connections close. So when the queue is full, you gonna get timeouts, till the current connections are closed. Other related problem, resource leaking.

Comment: I mean that when the browser sent 10 GET requests to load a website only 7 were picked up by the serverSocket.accept() method and created new Connection objects (This is starting with an empty queue). Thats a fair point, I have edited the Connection class to remove the return statements from the catch statements. However, the problem still persists.

Comment: I see, can you update here? so we can try to help you again with your new version; as your changes eliminate my answer.

Comment: Well, I am sorry I cannot help. I hope the answer was at least helpful, as the leaking was real. any way I was thinking about the threads, while the connections arrive you put on a blocking queue, the queue could be the delay, as the executor is reading and writing on it, and the connections are arriving fast. A new connection would have to wait till you get back to accept after this blocking operation. This should not avoid connections on the queue though - at most a delay. Except if the browser reaches its own timeout. If you find the answer please post here, I am curious.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thanks for pointing out that resource leak! It would be a delay but it shouldn't be a very long delay. If I try to load a separate page in a new tab while another tab is loading, the new GET requests are also not received by the proxy. So thats why I'm thinking there is something stopping the main thread from picking up the newer connections. I certainly will!